# Is there a way in vue to only display admin page for the admin user and show only to regular users regular pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

is there a way in vue that I can only show some views to normal users and all the views to the admin user?

I am using Firestore for my CRUD operations

For example:
I am the administrator, I can do CRUD functions and can access the whole site. While non-admin cannot do CRUD and can't access the admin page?

I'm thinking that I can do that in vue-router but I don't know how to implement that. Hope you can help me!

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => {
      return import('@/views/auth/vLoginLandingPage')
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/announcements',
    name: 'Announcements',
    component: () => {
      return import('@/views/drawer/announcement/vAnnouncementLandingPage')
    },

  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the beforeEnter hook in router to check is they are admin user or a normal user and take action accordingly. Something like the following:

```
const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => {
      return import('@/views/auth/vLoginLandingPage')
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/announcements',
    name: 'Announcements',
    beforeEnter: checkAdminRights
    component: () => {
      return import('@/views/drawer/announcement/vAnnouncementLandingPage')
    },

  }
]


function checkAdminRights(to, from, next) {
    // check if the user is admin
    if(userIsAdmin) {
        next({ path: '/adminroute'});       
    } else {
        next({ path: '/nonadminroute'});
    }
}
```

Function checkAdminRights will be called each time before a route change. You can check if the user is admin or not in this and can send to respective route on basis of that.

Comment: Could some malicious user change the VueJS code in his browser to enforce the routing to /adminroute?

Comment: Yes, they could. If /adminroute is populated by data from an api, you could use authentication/authorization on the api. Another option is server-side rendering (SSR) the app so that the http request `GET /adminroute` could require auth. Vue ssr: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html , Firestore auth: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/get-started

Answer (score 0):

Vue like other javascripts frameworks has role and permission packages, 
this is an amazing article in medium, explained with details to make role and use it.

https://medium.com/@manojkumar_88220/role-based-authentication-using-vue-js-2-f54e18498019

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Vue user, but I believe that authorization and authentication need to be done server-side.

Your Vue code is all going to be loaded onto the client's computer, so they could manipulate it if they wanted to.  Router could show and hide the pages, but you need to make sure that CRUD operations are validated server-side.